# Replace image in Photoshop keeping skew intact

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation, mockup, skew

How can I replace images in an array of images in Photoshop, such that the image retains all its properties?

I created a layer with an image and skewed the image to have a perspective look. I  then duplicated that layer twice. I want to change the images in the other copies without having to manually do it.

I tried

- Turning image into smart object and doing "replace contents". Image was replaced, but the skew didn't apply
- Created an action
- Doing it in InDesign

I have seen this kind of thing before in **isometric UX website design mockups** with many different mockups in the composite (I think I'm using the right terms). So, there must be an easy way to do it that essentially automates the process, but I haven't found it yet.

Here is a screenshot of my LinkedIn banner. The 3 monitors on the right are what I'm talking about:

[image: Eric Hepperle's LinkedIn profile banner with 3 monitors on left]

I hope this makes sense. If it doesn't, please let me know and I'll do my best to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn the layer into a **Smart Object** *first*, then transform/skew it. Converting a layer to a Smart Object *after* transformations is not the same. If you skew an *existing* Smart object, the skew is retained if you replace the SO contents.

If you want 3 layers, each with different *contents*, but the same transformations...

- Start with a standard layer
- Convert it to a Smart Object
- Transform/Skew it how you want.
- Highlight the Smart Object layer in the **Layers Panel** and then choose `New Smart Object Via Copy` from the **Layers Panel Menu**. (NOTE: This command is **not** the same as merely duplicating a Smart Object layer, although it may *seem* like it is by the name.)
- You can then replace the contents of the *new* Smart Object layer *without* altering the contents of any other Smart Object layers.

The *menu item* will create a new, *unlinked*, Smart Object with the same transformations. Replacing the contents of this new Smart Object, *won't* replace the contents of *other* smart objects.

Comment: Thanks Scott! I will give this a try and report back.